# How to change font-family in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The default Vuetify font family is Roboto and I would like to change this. I found other solutions that changes the font family globally. I don't want to change it globally, I only want to change it for a specific element. How to do this?

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <div class="text-h4">Text family I want to change</div>
        <div class="text-h6">Text family I dont want to change/give another font family</div>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Vuetify declares the font on `.v-application` and unfortunately also declare the font as `!important` on `.v-application .text-hN`. I can suggest you some ideas to modify your font:

1. If you want to change every text-h4: You can override the style of text-h4 by modifying its default ($headings then
   'h4') https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#example-variable-file
2. If you want to keep default text-h4: You can remove the `text-h4` class and use your own class `custom-header` with copied rules of text-h4 plus your font-family rule. You won't need higher specificity, nor to use !important.
   Something like:

> ```
> .custom-header {
>     font-size: 2.125rem !important; /* from .text-h4 */
>     line-height: 2.5rem; /* from .text-h4 */
>     letter-spacing: .0073529412em !important; /* from .text-h4 */
>     font-weight: 400; /* from .text-h4 */
>     font-family: YOUR_FONT_FAMILY, Roboto, sans-serif;
> }
> ```

---

**Previous answer**

Give your element another class:

```
<div class="text-h4 anotherClassForExample">Text family I want to change</div>
```

Override the font-family of this new class in your css.

---

I was in a similar position before, I had some basic css knowledge and started using frameworks. I strongly recommend you to master CSS before using a UI framework. Starting by using a framework looks faster, shinier and easier but in the long term it is not. You will be blocked a lot and maybe in the future you will change to another one or even want to not use any.

Comment: I actually tried this already before asking, and on retrospect, I should've also mentioned it. I actually did manage to fix it after asking, by adding a few more classes to increase specificity so that I can override the default font family. So the code turned out to be, ```<div class="text-h4 myFont1 myFont2 myFont3">Text family I want to change</div>``` and the css ```.myFont1.myFont2.myFont3{font-family: myFont !important;}```

Comment: I looked a little more in details to your problem, they declare the font on `.v-application` and unfortunately also declare the font as `!important` on `.v-application .text-hN`. I can suggest you some ideas to do it differently:

1) You can override the style of text-h4 by modifying its default ($headings then 
  'h4') https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#example-variable-file

2) Better if you want to keep default h4: You can remove the `text-h4` class and use your own class `custom-text-h4` with copied rules of text-h4 plus your font-family rule.